# centered hrule (plain tex)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules, plain-tex

As my nick suggests, I am just starting out with tex. Using plain tex, I am trying to create a document where certain paragraphs are separated by a centered horizontal line. I would like the separating line to be slighty larger than \hsize. I tried the following:

```
\parindent 0pt
\hsize 5in
{\hsize 6in \hrule}
\bigskip
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
%The "x x x ... x" above is the text of a dummy paragraph.
\bigskip
{\hsize 6in \hrule}
\vfill
\eject
\end
```

but it didn't work. The hrule width came out the *same* as the text width.

I would appreciate any advice as to how I can achieve the desired effect.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Are you looking for `\hrule width6in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hrule` draws a rule as wide as the vertical box enclosing it; since we're in the main vertical list and there's a paragraph, the width is the same as the `\hsize` used for the paragraph, so 5 inches.

You perhaps want `\hrule width 6in`:

```
\input plipsum

\parindent 0pt
\hsize 5in

\hrule width 6in
\bigskip
\lipsum{1}
\bigskip
\hrule width 6in

\bye
```

[image]

If you want the rule to stick half an inch at the left, some more work is needed

```
\input plipsum

\parindent 0pt
\hsize 5in

\moveleft.5in\vbox{\hrule width 6in}
\nointerlineskip
\bigskip
\lipsum{1}
\bigskip
\nointerlineskip
\moveleft.5in\vbox{\hrule width 6in}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I want the hrule to extend beyond \hsize both left and right I haven't tried any of the solutions posted by others yet, but your second proposed solution works perfectly.

Comment: @tex_novice I leave to you the necessary bits to avoid a page break between the rules and the text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\hrulefill` inside an `\hbox` of your desired width. Center this by putting it in `\centerline`.

I suggest adding some vertical space around the divider as well.

```
\def\divider{\par
  \vskip 1em
  \centerline{\hbox to 0.5\hsize{\hrulefill}}
  \vskip 1em
}

\beginsection Introduction

Dummy text.

\divider

\beginsection Conclusion

Dummy text.

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: After changing your 0.5 to 1.2, your solution also does the trick. Of the two solutions proposed so far, the output appears the same, Is there any advantage to one versus the other?

Comment: This version is perhaps more "semantic" in spirit, since it allows you to define the width relatively instead of hard-coding the inches.